# Add effect to any fields changing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am using React with `react-hook-form` and I'm trying to store every value user enters in `localStorage` to persist form state. I know I can redefine `onChange` handler library provides and add to actual handler storing its value, but I'm looking for solution, that allow to provide custom `onChange` or `onBlur` handler that I can provide to `useHook` and it will trigger on any field changes. Something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const methods = useForm({
    onChange: (allValues) => localStorage.setItem('form', allValues),
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@teehbow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72813407/13781208) got  me thinking about watch not only exact field value by its name, but the whole form. Reffering to [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch), if you don't pass field name to hook, you will get the object with all form values.

```
const name = useWatch('first-name') // watch and return only first name as string
const values = useWatch()           // watch all the form fields and returns form values object
```

If you don't wrap your form with `FormProvider`, then you also need to pass `control` to your watch hook. If you do, you can use it as in example above.

As I already have a value that subscribed to form changes, I only need to create effect that depends on values. To prevent unnecessary render of parent form element, i put out storing values to new component that do nothing but it

```
function PersistWatch(): null {
  const values = useWatch()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('key', values)
  }, [values])
  
  return null
}
```

and put this component inside `FormProvider`. And it works! Also it's possible to pass local storage key using props and it will make component reusable in different forms.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything to do this, but you can probably use something like this :

```
const { watch } = useForm();

const watchField1 = watch("field1");
const watchField2 = watch("field2");
const watchField3 = watch("field3");

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('form', {
    field1: watchField1,
    field2: watchField2,
    field3: watchField3,
  });
}, [watchField1, watchField2, watchField3]);
```

Comment: Yeah, it will work, but i have ten input form components and twenty form fields, its kinda even better to create custom handlers to every component rather than watch on every of twenty fields and rerender the whole form.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Maybe make a custom resolver to set your localstorage when validation is called ?